# What would realistically be the secret base for someone who can teleport?

Tags: internal-consistency, social-norms, secret-society

In this world, mutant animals and humans exist on earth, along with regular people. The MC can instantly teleport anywhere on earth freely (his super-power) no matter the distance, and can teleport objects he can touch up to the size of a small house.

The technology for mutant society ranges from primitive (bows and carriages) to modern tech we see today (guns, internet, cars, etc), but the normal humans have noticably superior tech like spaceships that can travel to other planets in the solar system, radar that auto detects DNA when something passes through it, machine soldiers sometimes almost indistinguishable from humans, manless self-operating factories that can mass produce stuff like food clothing and vehicles very quickly, supersonic bullet trains, etc.

The resources MC has access to personally: TV, PC, basic furniture, heat & air conditioning, alarm system, cloth-like body armor that defends against small-arms fire and blunt force (like falling off a building), a cell phone, a utility belt with a variety of situational items, a powerful AI inside his sanctuary very similar to a person (which he can talk to through a device on his armor).

He doesn't want others to access or know about his sanctuary, both humans and mutants. What is a feasible place for him to live?

The mutants have various abilities including but not limited to: flight, super speed & strength, project lightning & fire and other elements, telekinesis, etc.

It's a post-apocalypse, mutants live in areas outside civilization, like forests or abandoned cities, while humans band together in fortified areas.

Comment: How does he get his furniture and other cool toys into his secret base with no doors?

Comment: How much can the MC carry whilst teleporting? After all "the moon" might be a nice retreat, but if there's no means of getting life-support there then it's out of the question. We would also need to know what they can have access to, what resources do they have personally, also when you say teleport, how far? After all there's a splendid Earth-like planet two galaxies over that would be lovely. Please add details to make the question answerable.

Comment: Also, how well does the MC need to know about where they are going? That is, can they 'scan' for a landing zone, must they have made the trip in person at least once, something else?

Comment: @ARogueAnt. I edited the question so that those details are explained! I apologize for my mistakes!

Comment: The blunt force from a fall is different from being hit by a club or car. When a club hits you, you can spread out the kinetic force, divert the kinetic shock away from vital organs and spread the acceleration of your body over a longer period. In the meantime a fall can only be safely done by slowing the body over a distance. Surviving a fall from a building requires more than a meter thick air-matras that deflates upon impact while the body is in the right position, not something regular clothing can help you with.

Comment: Can your teleporter cancel out velocity when they teleport? If no, they may want a large room with nets/foam cubes scattered everywhere so that they can avoid taking damage from falls or absorbing their speed when teleporting from a moving vehicle like a car. Additionally, an unrestricted teleporter like this should have several hypo- and hyperbaric chambers always on standby so that they can't be trapped by a prepared foe inside a pressurized chamber where tp'ing out would kill them from decompression sickness.

Comment: The character teleports by manipulating space, so I'd assume they can cancel out velocity. But I never considered decompression sickness, it's a relatively new concept to me lol. Man, that sounds scary

Comment: I suggest you watch the movie Jumper if you haven't already. It's a near identical scenario to what you describe, and might give you some ideas. As for the base, anywhere underground would do to be honest. To avoid suspicion, your MC could "live" in a small apartment as a cover.

Comment: This is verging on "close because it's plot-based". We need a *lot* more information about the other mutants, so we know what the teleporter has to hide from. In particular, if some kind of supernatural sense allows another mutant to detect people anywhere in the world, then no-one gets to have a secret base ever. All you have is a non-secret base which takes impractical levels of effort for other people to reach.

Comment: His/Her Personnel Washroom/Toilet, Closet, Garage. AnyWhere anybody can spend many hours enjoy themselves alone.

Comment: So, infinite energy, but the guy chooses to do what instead? be a vigilante? (also, note that this power immediately also grant most of the other powers. Flying, Strength, Speed, Telekinesis, to name only the obvious)

Answer (score 29):

Hide it in plain sight.

You seem to have reasonable carte blanche when it comes to the secret base. One problem with the ideas so far is that you could be tracked down by your use of electricity, water or heat. So instead you build an apartment complex with several tenants. You own an appartment on the bottom (or if it's luxurious enough you own the entire bottom). Beneath the utilities basement you have another basement where you will build the base of operations. Perhaps make it some off-the-books work with the contractor so it doesn't show up on the building plans.

You make sure the ventilation system of the building is connected to the lowest basement. You then do some work so the electrics and water of the basement are drawn from the apartment you own. This way any electric and water usage will not be unnoticed.

Make the bottom basement a gym for a short time (or have illegal activities take place there, out of your knowledge of course). Eventually the gym will be shut down for monetary or legal reasons and you brick it up completely.

Now you have a basement that is there, people even know it's there, but it's no longer accessible and in use, right? There's hundreds of small sections no longer in use all over the city, doors and rooms that some people know technically exist but you walk past it because there's nothing there. It's ventilated, it has running water and electricity that are billed to an address, and since it's an apartment complex no one can wonder why there is random heat or electricity at that point, especially since it's right beneath the utilities basement where you likely have the central water heater and electric circuits for the building. And hey you live there, so you can also sit back and relax whenever you feel like it.

Comment: In plain sight. Hide a tree in a forest

Comment: What does he/she even need a secret basement for? Why can’t he live like a normal human?

Comment: @Michael to hide his secret stuff! Otherwise there would be no question on hiding his secret base now would there? Perhaps it has a few trophies, like when he fought the supervillain who could tie superhero shoelaces of both shoes together very quickly. Or he could have illegal weapons stashed there, like his squidlauncher. Dont want to have your friends walk in and ask "whats that?" And you hope you can convince them its an obscure sex toy.

Comment: I'd probably pick a "legacy" apartment building with master metering for this, even -- it'd be much less likely to get noticed than an individually metered setup

Answer (score 11):

We'll assume that our teleporter can carry at least some light items with them while teleporting; otherwise, establishing a secret hideout is going to be pretty darned rustic.

Were I the teleporter, I'd probably establish my hideout in an inaccessible forested extinct volcano, a place like [Mount Lico](https://www.techtimes.com/articles/231554/20180702/scientists-explore-secret-rainforest-hidden-in-volcanic-crater-in-africa.htm) or the [Kahuku Forested Pit Crater](https://www.nps.gov/places/forested-pit-crater.htm).  Such places would have the advantage of being inaccessible to all but the flying mutants, and the dense forest would allow the teleporter to build a habitation that would be hidden even from them.  Unlike glaciers, outer space, or cave systems, they wouldn't have issues with temperature, breathable air, or water supply.  In tropical zones, solar panels could supply electricity.  They could even have a garden.

Comment: Please don't answer ill-defined questions. Leave a comment, then wait for the question to be edited into shape.

Comment: The question hasn't been closed, which means it's taking answers.

Comment: The question is blatantly ill-defined and as such shouldn't be answered until it's been edited, else when it's closed it can't be edited into shape for fear of invalidating existing answers. The old [close - open](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7797/we-are-too-ready-to-close-questions-how-to-change-this) issue that gets asked in meta so frequently and closed as a duplicate.

Comment: Pretty sure that adding solar panels would make it pretty easy to spot from the air, though, invalidating the entire point of hiding it in the forest to begin with.

Comment: Nick: yeah, that would be a tradeoff.  However, a few solar panels wouldn't be as much as a giveaway as a noisy generator.

Answer (score 6):

Kerguelen Islands, Southern Indian Ocean

> [Situated more than 2,000 miles away from civilization, these islands in the southern Indian Ocean are also known as the Desolation Islands due to their incredibly remote location. Grande Terre is the biggest island in the volcanic archipelago, a French territory consisting of 300 islands covering an area about the size of Delaware.
> There are no native people living in the Kerguelen Islands, but a small population of scientists ranging from about 50 in the winter to 100 in the summer live and conduct research in the only settlement, Port-aux-Français. The only way to travel to the Kerguelen Islands is by a ship that leaves only four times a year.](https://www.treehugger.com/most-remote-places-on-earth-4869276#:%7E:text=The%20volcanic%20island%20of%20Tristan,on%20Earth%20inhabited%20by%20humans.)

Find an island with no scientists, or if there are scientists go about 60 miles away and there is virtually no chance of getting found. If you do get found you have three months to leave. making it hard to get to you doesn't matter, mutants and dedicated humans will get you eventually, the only way to be sure no one can get to you is make it so they don't know where you are.

Comment: Given the edits, I'm going to double down on my answer. With flight, fireproofing, and super strength, no place is impenetrable. However, the chance that someone can or will search large swaths of wilderness for you is very low.

Comment: @ARogueAnt.I edited the post! Please review it and see if it's up to par! I don't want another one of my questions closed

Answer (score 6):

Imagine a building and a hidden room, without windows or doors (but with ventilation and with power, if there is still such a thing). Everybody who thinks about complete floor plans (if they still exist) will realize that there is a cavity somewhere, but there will be perfectly logical reasons why it is inaccessible now. Perhaps an elevator was added at a later time, and it blocked access to one of the flats. Or there was a swimming pool added at a lower floor, and it blocks access to yet another set of rooms.

Comment: Best would be "service" rooms on top of flats or skyscrapers. Se for basements.

Answer (score 3):

There are several excellent examples given throughout the course of the *Jumper* series by Steven Gould (I highly recommend reading all four books in the main series whenever given the opportunity). The main character's first "base" is simply a nondescript apartment in Manhattan, where he has walled off a closet so that only he can access

> the funds acquired through his bank robbery (he previously hid the money in duffel bags in the ceiling of the library in his home town).

He also rents an apartment in a college town, though this is primarily to feel close to his girlfriend who attends the college.

He eventually develops his first true secret base, a cliffside cave he walls off deep in a wilderness area in Texas; he also acquires a few ravine oases in the same region that he initially uses for swimming, but eventually uses as a convenient place to

> deposit terrorists and federal agents while figuring out what to do with them.

The end of the second book is marked by the decision to purchase a house isolated somewhere in the Canadian wilderness. This house was built by someone else, uses geothermal energy for energy independence, and they never access the internet or phone system from it.

The third book tackles what is actually a bigger problem: connecting back with society after living anonymously on the fringes. Focusing primarily on the daughter attending high school using an assumed identity and detailing a bit of the technical tricks used to dodge digital detection, we also get to see a glimpse of the main characters' humanitarian efforts: warehouses scattered throughout the world, filled with bags of humanitarian items that can be carried by a single person, psychological tricks used to deflect attention from someone who could've sworn there wasn't somebody standing there a moment ago.....

The third book also introduces the concept that

> the ability to match inertial frames implies the ability to change velocity while jumping;

but I include it in this paragraph because it is in the fourth book that the daughter uses this ability to

> establish her own space program.

Items like air pressure and decompression are mentioned briefly in previous books, but here they obviously take center stage in a book that

> puts the ultimate teleporter's not-so-secret-but-very-hard-to-reach base in an inflatable habitat in orbit.

Also meriting brief mention is the possibility of purchasing a defunct hotel in some unknown urban area; and the close, which sees

> the daughter handing a friend a container of soil from Mars

can inspire other ideas, which may unfortunately be a little too far out of your stated scope.

Answer (score 2):

**Deep under the ice**

The power to teleport anywhere instantly together with an object the size of a small house is very, very powerful. It means the MC (Mutant Character?) can take basically *anything* she/he desires that conforms to the weight limit.

First go to either the North or South pole and teleport some blocks of Ice away. Next find something like a small nuclear bunker or simply a box of reinforced concrete. Do make sure it can stand up to massive cold, but it's likely not going to be too cold due to the insulating properties of ice. Important is that it needs to be fully waterproof. Possibly you need to teleport it elsewhere first to treat it to be waterproof, or find somewhere that already has happened. Make sure that there is plenty of insulation on the inside. This is not only to prevent heat from escaping, it is also to prevent the ice surrounding it from melting and detection by heat sensors.

Next you install some pipes for air ventilation. Thanks to heat exchange pipes you can have normal air come in and cold air go out  like the blood veins in your arms and legs exchanging heat. Install a few pumps and some air reservoirs and you can fill any remainder of the hole with water or ice. You can also still increase the size of the sanctuary at this stage with modular components. Best would be to stack the modular components to make the sanctuary profile as small as possible for the most likely eyes: satellites from above.

Also make a pipe down if there's water there, or sideways for a water intake.

With that done you can proceed to get two incredibly important components. Hydrogen electric cells and electrolysis machines. The one turns water into hydrogen and oxygen. One you can breathe while the other you can burn for heat/cooking or put into the hydrogen cells for electricity and water. This is similar to some submarines and leaves basically no trace of obvious waste. Extra energy is still needed from, for example, a deep-sea tide generator or the like. Something that can cleanly produce energy away from prying eyes. Alternatively you just teleport some hydrogen canisters with you once in a while, making your base more stealthy. With that sorted you can potentially lock down the whole sanctuary where nothing goes out temporarily. You store excess air and personal waste in the canisters earlier installed, while still being supplied with oxygen and electricity.

Now you've got a functioning base. Deep under the ice it's unlikely to be seen by satellites and the cold prevents most people from going there. Best would probably be the south pole, where the structure can rest on the island underneath. This will support the structure as well as hide it better to things trying to look through the ice. You can also tunnel under the base to try to use geothermal power for the extra electricity.

Furnish it, paint it, make it homely and add the AI. You're ready to stealthily conduct any operation staged from one of the most remote and secluded areas in the world. It is possible with the aid of teleportation and rudimentary skills in construction to make this yourself, although electrical skills for the advanced stuff is required. Possibly the AI can make exact plans for the MC to make it as simple as IKEA (Where is that red cable!?).

Only one problem. If you're talking to your AI it means transmission. The transmission can't "hide" in the plethora of signals sent from other sources, as there are practically none on the poles. Any such signal would stand out and be investigated. Otherwise you can't get much more secluded that this.

Comment: MC=Main Character

Comment: "Make sure that there is plenty of insulation on the inside. This is not only to prevent heat from escaping, it is also to prevent the ice surrounding it from melting and detection by heat sensors." This will happen inevitably anyway, as long as the interior is greater than 0 degrees Celsius. There's a reason why Antarctic bases are kept at that temperature indoors.

Answer (score 0):

Let the villains plan and build and pay for the secret hideouts.

Move into one (or more) after the villains are done with them (incarcerated, dead, amnesiac, etc). Block access so that henchmen and previous occupants cannot conveniently return.

When a powerful villain returns and wants their lair back, move on to another "abandoned" hideout instead of fighting for the real estate. Alternately, the teleporter can use their detailed knowledge of the hideout to trap Mr Badguy during their next conflict.

In the meantime, clever villains will have arranged ways to keep the utilities turned on, so the teleporter can use that. The teleporter can sleep in Mr Badguy's bed, eat Mr Badguy's food, and peruse Mr Badguy's internet...possibly for many years until Mr Badguy's untraceably hidden funds are exhausted.

Answer (score 0):

/ manless self-operating factories that can mass produce stuff like food clothing and vehicles/

Hide out in there!  I like manless because I don't need no sausage party in my hideout, and I like stuff like food even if it is mass produced.  I don't want to hide out anywhere that I run out of food and water, ever.  Running out of clothes would be ok but still some swanky clothes make a hiding hero feel put together.  As regards vehicles I would set up a race course in there to test out the various vehicles including those 3-wheeled cars (not the Mr Bean kind; the sweet kind).

The AI in charge of the factory is romantically involved with the powerful AI I have in my hideout, who is named Powerful.  I have to remind Powerful to treat Factory right and not to screw it up because the free food and clothing and vehicles thing works for me and it would be hard to get done anywhere else, or at least not done so well.  I tell Factory that because I think most people don't appreciate how hard it is to run a manless factory.  "Factory" is such a harsh word but the factory is actually an awesome place to live.